# Using jQuery in React to modify CSS of an element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

[image]

Hello,
I know its not recommended to use jQuery with react & I am aware of method on react for changing CSS of element but here I am just trying to see if my req can be achieved or not , all i want is to change the colour of li element when corresponding tick icon is clicked for it, I am using a jQuery code

```js
const markdone = () => {
  let c = $("#ll")
  console.log(c)
  $(c).closest("li").css("background-color", "green");
};
```

but when i am clicking the css gets applied but not on its corresponding li element in my case for ex have attached image when i click on 3 tick icon css gets changed for 1 is there any way i can fix it
attaching whole code below

check  markdone function for making css change :

```js
const [input, setValue] = useState("");
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
// passing  entered
const handleInput = (event) => {
  setValue(event.target.value);
};

const lp = (event) => {
  // let c = [1,2,34,55]

  event.preventDefault();
  // if no input nothing will happen return none
  if (!input) return;
  // using spread operator its used whenever we need to add array data to exiting array
  const newTodos = [...todos, input];

  setTodos(newTodos);
  // clearing input text
  setValue("");

};
const handeldel = (index) => {
  // console.log(index)

  todos.splice(index, 1);
  setTodos([...todos]);

  // const newTodos = todos.splice(index, 1);
  // setTodos([...newTodos]);
};
const [line, setline] = useState(false);
// const [ll, setll] = useState(false);
const markdone = () => {
  let c = $("#ll")
  console.log(c)
  $(c).closest("li").css("background-color", "green");
};

useEffect(() => {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#pk").click(function(e) {
      // e.preventDefault();
      alert('hello')


    });



  });


});

return ( <
    div >
    <
    h1 id = "pk"
    className = "text-center font-weight-bolder alert-info mb-5" >
    Tasks To Do < i class = "fas fa-clipboard-list text-success" > < /i> <
    /h1> <
    div class = "input-group mb-3 container" >
    <
    input className = "form-control border-primary font-weight-bold"
    style = {
      {
        height: 60
      }
    }
    placeholder = "Enter Text here"
    type = "text"
    value = {
      input
    }
    onChange = {
      handleInput
    }
    /> <
    div class = "input-group-append" >
    <
    button className = "input-group-append font-weight-bolder "
    style = {
      {
        fontSize: 20
      }
    }
    onClick = {
      lp
    } >
    {
      " "
    } <
    i class = "fas fa-plus-square fa-2x p-2" > < /i>{" "} <
    /button> <
    /div> <
    /div> {
      todos.map((x, index) => ( <
        ol style = {
          {
            listStyle: "outside"
          }
        }
        className = "container" >
        <
        li className = "font-weight-bolder table-bordered text-capitalize alert-secondary "


        style = {
          {
            fontSize: 30,
            textDecoration: line ? "line-through" : "none",
            // backgroundColor: ll ? "Chartreuse" : "none",

          }
        } >
        {
          x
        } <
        i class = "fas fa-check-circle float-md-right text-success"
        id = "ll"
        onClick = {
          markdone
        } >
        < /i>{" "} <
        i class = "fas fa-trash-alt  text-danger float-md-right"
        onClick = {
          () => handeldel(index)
        } >
        < /i> <
        /li> <
        /ol>
      ))
    }

    { /* for future ref */ } {
      /* <div >
              {data.map((user) => (
                <div className="user">{user.id + "  " + user.name 
                }</div>
              ))}
            </div> */
    } <
    /div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose using a [Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) should do the trick, as Refs provide a way to access DOM nodes or React elements created in the render method.
Just put it on the element you'd like to style using jQuery and access it with RefName.current

Answer (score 0):

1. IDs must be unique
2. You do not need jQuery, just delegation

Plain JS - there are other ways in React

I am assuming .input-group-append is the container

---

```
document.querySelector(".input-group-append").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("text-success")) {
    tgt.closest("li").style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
})
```

Comment: There are react ways too